# how to run a code in php just after a file is created in a folder?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to run a code after file is created using file_get_contents(). Right now when i call the code to load the xml file using simplexml_load_file() it do nothing because the file take time to load and save in a folder using file_get_contents().

If i got any way that the code will work just after when a file is created in the folder then i think this job will be done. here is my code which i want to run

```
 if(file_exists("cache/cache_file.xml")){
$offerxml = simplexml_load_file("cache/cache_file.xml");
$hotel = $offerxml->offer;

$resultpage = count($hotel) / 10;
?>
<div class="pagination_btn_cont">
<?php for($btn=1;$btn<=$resultpage;$btn++){?>
<div class="pagination_btn"><?php echo $btn;?></div>
<?php } ?>
</div><!--pagination_btn_cont ends--> 
<?php } ?>
</div><!--search_result_cont ends here-->
```

but this code do nothing because the file at that time is not load completely.

Comment: how is 'cache/cache_file.xml' being saved? is a process external to PHP who saves it?

Comment: ys its saving through another php script which i am calling through ajax it display the xml data. i have use there file_get_content("cache/cache.xml", content)
but it takes time to load till then my above code to load xml via file do not work because file is not exists till that time

Answer (score 0):

The function `file_exists()` wants an absolute path, your passing a relative one, use DOCUMENT_ROOT to provide the former. Besides you can check for the file once in a second, with a maximum wait, like this:

```
$wait = 8; //maximum wait set to 8 seconds
while(!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."cache/cache_file.xml") && $wait){
    sleep(1);
    $wait--;
}

if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "cache/cache_file.xml")){
    $offerxml = simplexml_load_file("cache/cache_file.xml");
    $hotel = $offerxml->offer;
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: its showing me error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: yes it had an error, I've fixed it, check my updated answer. Also take in mind you weren't checking for the correct file, so maybe the problem was only that.

Comment: no i am looking for the correct file. Its not showing pagination because the file isnot load on time and the simplexml_load_function() starts load the file. if i refresh the page after loading the complete result then the pagination start display